# Tony Stark and MIT

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

In the cinematography universe of Marvel, it was never mentioned about Stark's educational qualifications, but his expertise in fields such as nano Electronics, nuclear physics, high energy physics are invariably shown in certain scenes of the moves. Did Tony graduate with a honours from MIT and if so what were his specializations then?

Comment: _"And at 17, he graduated summa cum laude from MIT."_

Answer (score 2):

> Did Tony graduate with a honours from MIT and if so what were his specializations then?

### Not exactly...

> In the movie version, they say that Stark graduated "summa cum laude" from MIT. Of course, **MIT doesn't have Latin honors, or a valedictorian, or class rank, or anything like that.**
>
> [Source](https://mitadmissions.org/blogs/entry/iron_man_mit_87/)

So he just graduated from MIT with the necessary qualifications...but what were they?

That's a little murkier.

> A proud affiliation notwithstanding, little is known about Stark’s time at MIT. His academic record is sealed and existing public information is inconsistent. MIT Admissions tentatively lists Stark as receiving his undergraduate degree in 1987 but Marvel Comics claims **he received two master’s degrees in engineering by age 19**. Confusing matters more, a recently deleted LinkedIn profile for Tony Stark indicated he received **doctorates in engineering physics and artificial intelligence.**
>
> [Source](https://alum.mit.edu/slice/who-iron-man)

Comment: Also - https://www.quora.com/What-qualifications-or-degrees-might-Tony-Stark-have